# Doctrine Entity 3 levels deep relationship is persisting to the GrandChild from Parent Insert

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, relationship, persist

I have a unique situation where we have a Doctrine (2.6) relationship that is 3 levels in depth.

**The relationship is loosely defined as follows:**

*Many-to-One Relationship*

1. User (Parent) *[user_id]*
2. Address (Child) *[user_id,city_id]*
3. City (Grand-Child) *[city_id]*

If I create a User(Parent), the Address(Child) is created simultaneously - this is perfect.

However there is always an attempt at creating a new record in the City(Grand-Child) object/table persisted to the DataBase.

I am only ever interested in the City Entity at the time of Querying/Fetching/Viewing, with it being joined (if possible) based on the city_id of the Parent [Address].

*Changes to the City Data are managed externally, not a concern in this instance*

How do I setup the relationship to ensure that Inserts into the **User** (Parent) only write/persist to Itself and the **Address** (Parent) - AND NOT THE **CITY** (Grand-Child)